# Did the author base this element on the Rubaiyat?

Tags: edward-fitzgerald, omar-khayyam, persian-language, the-rubaiyat

In a non-fiction history book, *Millennium: A History of the Last Thousand Years*, a (temporarily) recurring element is "The Tower of Darkness".

Chapter 3 is even titled that, and it's fairly clearly referring to the Islamic empire or caliphate and its rule of a significant portion of Eurasia.

When searching to find whether the author made that phrase up, I found it's from Edward FitzGerald's English translation of *The Rubaiyat of Omar Khayyam*:

> A Muezzin from the Tower of Darkness cries
>   "Fools! Your reward is neither Here nor There!"

Is there any direct evidence that the author of the history book got this phrase from the Rubaiyat?